# How to simplify or approximate n^2 choose n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, approximation

I'm analyzing the runtime of an algorithm I wrote. I determined that there are

${{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \choose n}$ $\approx$ ${n^2 \choose n}$  = $\frac{n^2!}{n!(n^2-n)!}$ operations in the algorithm.

However I do not know how to simplify this further.  I also could be completely off, as I do not have a math major.

Can someone help with this analysis?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you do not make the approximation
$$A_n=\binom{\frac{n(n-1) }{2} }{n}=\frac{\left(\frac{n(n-1) }{2} \right)! }{n! \,\left(\frac{n(n-3) }{2} \right)! }$$ Now, take logarithms and, as Ross Millikan suggested, use Stirling approximation
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12
   p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ This would give
$$\log(A_n)=n \left(\log \left({n}\right)+1-\log (2)\right)-\frac{1}{2} \left(\log
   \left({n}\right)+4+\log (2 \pi )\right)-\frac{5}{4 n}-\frac{4}{3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which is quite accurate as soon as $n >3$ as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 4 & 2.70805 & 2.76467 \\
 5 & 5.52943 & 5.55446 \\
 6 & 8.51819 & 8.53149 \\
 7 & 11.6638 & 11.6717 \\
 8 & 14.9495 & 14.9546 \\
 9 & 18.3603 & 18.3638 \\
 10 & 21.8833 & 21.8858 \\
 11 & 25.5079 & 25.5097 \\
 12 & 29.2249 & 29.2263 \\
 13 & 33.0269 & 33.0280 \\
 14 & 36.9073 & 36.9082 \\
 15 & 40.8606 & 40.8613
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $k!\approx \frac {k^k}{e^k}\sqrt{2\pi k}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a routine derived from [Wikipedia's article on Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_in_programming_languages) to calculate the exact value. This works pretty well, uses only exact integer arithmetic in Python, and is time complexity `O(n)`. Remember that in Python, `range(n)` produces a list from `0` through `n – 1`.

```
def n_squared_choose_n(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    nsqr = n * n
    c = 1
    for i in range(n):
        c = c * (nsqr - i) / (i + 1)
    return c
```

This is based on the "simplification"

$${n^2 \choose n}=\frac{n^2}{1}\cdot\frac{n^2-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n^2-2}{3}\cdot\cdots\frac{n^2-n+1}{n}$$

which may well be good enough for your purposes.